# Copy bigquery view to another region

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to copy a view from project A (region: EU) to project B (region: US). There are many posts and articles about how to copy a dataset or table but for view it is different. there is no export to gcs option so I would not be able to export to gcs.
The view is using two other views and those views are using several other views and tables.
Worst and only solution I found: Should I copy all the tables first and then create new views in the destination project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is simply a request embedded in an object. There is no data in the view, and you can't perform multi-region requests.

Therefore you can't change the region of a view without moving the related data.

In official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) this limitation is mentioned as follows:

> You **cannot** run a BigQuery job that exports data from a **view**.